# Geany windows size and position

Tags: console, geany

How can you specify the windows size and position when running Geany from a command line. Usually this is done as

```
-g, --geometry string
```

Where you specify the size and location of the window, using the standard X window geometry syntax: WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a Year after question, but it might help others ...

This is a way to modify position and size at any time.

Debian Linux has (had?) preinstalled [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), which can move and resize windows.

Moves window to position 300 20 and sets size to 100 x 10 (in console/terminal):

```
geany_find() { xdotool search Geany 2>/dev/null | sed 1q; }
geany_x_y_w_h() { WINDOW=`geany_find`; xdotool windowsize $WINDOW $1 $2; }
geany_x_y_w_h 300 20 100 10
```

It has false positives because it searches windows by name, so Firefox with tab opened with this question ("console - Geany...") might might get resized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the geany window to always open using certain dimensions, you can just open it normally and change the size of the window. By default geany remembers the size of it's window.

if it doesn't, you can go to Edit, then preferences, select the general tab and then the start up tab, and finally make sure "Save window position and geometry" is checked.

Comment: Thanks. I would still prefer to set the window geometry from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `geometry` line in the configuration file, and run `geany`:

```
sed -i "/geometry=.*/c\geometry=x;y;sh;sv;0;" ~/.config/geany/geany.conf
geany &
```

or subscribe this format if you're using a variable:

```
newgeometry="geometry=x;y;sh;sv;0"
sed -i "/geometry=.*/c $newgeometry" ~/.config/geany/geany.conf
geany &
```

where these parameters are referred to the `geany` window:
- *x* is the horizontal coordinate of the left-top corner
- *y* is the vertical coordinate of the left-top corner
- *hs* is the size in the horizontal axis
- *vs* is the size in the vertical axis

Note: `sed` is a canonical command, it should work fine.